# How many random string can I generate with random_bytes(3) in PHP?

Tags: php

Is there a formula to get a total number of permutations for random_bytes($length) after converting to hex via bin2hex function? Let's say random_bytes(3)

Comment: `2 ^ (8 * $length)`

Comment: ...or `(6 + 10)^6`...

Answer (score 1):

random_bytes generates bytes.

1 byte = 8 bits. Ref: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte

Each bit can have 2 states, that is 0 and 1.

So you calculate it like follows.

(2) ^ (number of total bits)

```
2 ^ ($length * 8)

2 ^ (3 * 8)

2 ^ 24

16777216
```

Answer (score -1):

Could it be 36^3 = 46656 combinations? Cos random_bytes produces 36 positions (26 alphabets and 10 numbers as in abcdefghijklmnoprstuvwxyz0123456789)

I'm bad in maths.